# ExtJS Call method from modal view

Tags: extjs

I have a method in a form that creates a shows a Modal with a form in it.

```
onButtonClickSave: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    //Create modal form
    var confirm = new Ext.Window({
      xtype: 'form',
      hidden: true,
      itemId: 'FrmModalConfirma',
      layout: 'auto',
      bodyPadding: 10,
      items: [
      {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Are you sure?',
        labelWidth: 500
      },
      {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        width: 500,
        fieldLabel: 'Reason',
        labelWidth: 150,
        store: [
        [
        '2',
        'Death'
        ],
        [
        '3',
        'Birth'
        ],
        [
        '4',
        'Job'
        ],
        [
        '5',
        'Debt'
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [
        {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Yes',
          listeners: {
            click: 'onButtonClickCalculate'
          }
        },
        {
          xtype: 'tbspacer',
          width: 30
        },
        {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'No, cancel'
        }
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
    //Show modal form
    confirm.show();
  }
```

But when I click on the button that should execute this code:

```
onButtonClickCalculate: function(button, e, eOpts) {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Yes', 'It works');
}
```

I get this error on the browser: **Ext.util.Event.getFireInfo(): No method named "onButtonClickGuardaRecalcula" on sbs.view.admin.PrincipalViewController**  but all of this has been created in a panel named admin.StudentViewController. My first guess is that it is because the modal has been created using new Ext.Window but my lack of experience in ExtJS has me completely lost about this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like your function onButtonClickCalculate is outside the scope. Hence it cannot find it. Try putting that function directly and let's see what happens.

Comment: What do you mean by putting the function directly?

Comment: rather than putting click: 'onButtonClickCalculate' put something like this click: function () { alert('eeee');}

Comment: Thanks, indeed it now executes the method, however, I try to run this inside this method: this.getView().down('#FrmAdminIngresos').getForm(); and it says getView is not a function. How would I be able to call the forms on the modal's parent? Yuo should put this as an answer so I can upvote it and choose it if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things. When you try `this.getView()` you are getting function not found because you are in the scope of window not the view...does that makes sense :)

Ok here is what you can try. Before your `var confirm = new Ext.Window` put this

```
var that = this;
```

Then in handler add the property

```
scope: that,
handler: function() {
    this.getView()..... 
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thank you, as you said in your comment to my question, it was better to create the whole function inside the modal instead of trying to call it from another scope. The other error I came across was solved using var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FormName")[0]; instead of this.getView()